# Substituir um caractere de uma string por um asterisco

Tags: c

A questão é a seguinte: Faça um programa que leia um texto (string) digitado pelo usuário com no máximo 500 caracteres. Imprima esse texto substituindo a primeira letra de cada palavra por um asterisco '*'.

Ler os 500 caracteres eu consegui fazer:

```
printf("Digite uma palavra (tamanho maximo de 500 letras):");
gets(palavra);
```

Estou com dificuldades para entender o que fazer. Preciso que a `palavra[i]!='\0'`

Se usar o `for` ficaria algo assim?

```
for (i=0; palavra[i]!='\0' ; i++ )
{
    for (i=0 ; palavra[i]<'\0'; i++ )
    { 
        while (palavra[i]==palavra[i+1])
        {
           palavra[i]=' ';
           achou=1;
           printf ("%c\n\n", palavra[i]);
           i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não uses `gets()`. É impossível usar essa função com segurança e existe outra função muito parecida que podes substituir: `fgets()`. Além disso, a função que usas não faz parte da definição da linguagem C na última versão publicada (existia em C99, foi retirada em C11).

Answer (score 1):

Para iterar sobre uma string em C normalmente se faz assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char s[128];
    gets(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i) {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

O que voce escreveu faz mais ou menos a mesma coisa, mas nao precisa do `for` dentro do primeiro `for`.

Agora, usualmente uma palavra e um conjunto de caracteres entre espacos. Logo, toda vez que voce encontrar um espaco voce pode trocar a letra seguinte por um '*'. Algo como:

```
if (s[i] == ' ') {
    s[i + 1] = '*';
}
```

Claramente, tomando cuidado para ver se a string nao termina com um espaco.

Comment: Legal a resposta, mas eu acrescentaria no if o teste `s[i + 1] != '\0'` tambem, para ficar completinho, em vez de só avisar.

Comment: Muito obrigado galera!

Comment: Muito obrigada galera! Me ajudou muito! A primeira letra também precisava ser trocada pelo asterisco, então coloquei palavra[1]='*'.

Comment: @Karla a primeira letra e `palavra[0]`, tome cuidado.

Comment: É verdade, obrigada!